# Numbers whose power has digits that add up to the number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I noticed (with the help of the Instagram algorithm) that there are certain numbers, that when raised to a certain power, have a result whose digits add up to the original base.

Some examples of this are $9^2, 7^4, 36^5,$ so on and so forth.

I was wondering if there was a list somewhere of every number that has this property, so I could try to find some sort of pattern to this. If not, I bet I could probably make something in google sheets to generate a list of numbers that do this.

I also made a working spreadsheet that gave lots of results, I'll post my findings once I collect them and make them look a bit nicer.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: appreciate it thanks

Comment: http://oeis.org/A023052 (OEIS is always a good place to start looking for sequences). However, that doesn't include 36, so I may have to dig deeper or I found an error in OEIS

Comment: @BarryCarter That sequence is different than the one here. A023052 are numbers that are a sum of the digits which are themselves raised to powers like $153=1^3+5^3+3^3$, not a sum of the digits of a power of the number like $9^2=81$ with $9=8+1$.

Comment: @RossMillikan https://oeis.org/A023106 “a(n) is a power of the sum of its digits.”

Comment: Any thoughts on an upper bound for the exponents when searching for a given base?

Comment: Messing around on Python, I found some larger examples, such as $201384^{8479}$ has a digit sum of $201384$.

Comment: Are you only interested in base $10$, or also in other bases?

Comment: Yeah I thought of maybe doing that yesterday, with lower or higher bases than base ten we might find an upper bound more easily and use that to find something for base 10 but I honestly don't know. I'm still totally new to number theory and how people even begin to look for an answer. I'll definitely keep whoever's watching this thread posted though.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote [a couple of blog posts](https://blog.plover.com/math/power-digit-sum.html) about these a while back and included a list of the first few dozen examples, up to  $265^{28}$.

Some numbers with this property are sometimes called [*Dudeney numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dudeney_number).

[OEIS](https://oeis.org/A023106) has more information, including [a list of the first 1138 examples](https://oeis.org/A023106/b023106.txt).